# Rest Assured Framework - Handle Bearer Token, X Api key for Apigee proxy URL

Tags: rest-assured, api-key, bearer-token, apigee, rest

I am trying to create Test Automation framework for Apipgee Proxy URLs.

I am using Rest Assured Framework for Apigee proxy URLs with generating Bearer token on the fly ,Xapi Keyand use Apigee proxy URL. For now token is generated manually using CURL command . I can test well in postman.
// accessToken,apiKey below is defined as string
// inputrequest.getInputStream() reads JSON needed for body

```
response= RestAssured
           .given()
           .headers("Authorization","Bearer "+ accessToken)
           .headers("apiKey", apiKeyVar)
           .contentType("application/json")
           .body(inputrequest.getInputStream()).When()
           .post(apigeeProxyURL).then().statusCode(200).extract().response();
```

I am getting 401 (Unauthorized error) instead of 200. My query here to summarize--

1. Does RestAssured Framework Supports Apigee Proxy URL .
2. if same x-api Key and Bearer token works in postman for same end point, why its throwing an error
3. I read some blogs with variation on how to pass x-api Key and Bearer Token

Please revert back and share directions on how to approach for REST API Automation for Apigee Proxy URLs

Thanks and Regards,
Aditya Mandlekar

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are passing the apikey at the correct place . By default it should pass in the query param. Check your verifyapikey policy which you must have attached to your proxy.

Comment: Sure Ashish-thanks for response. I will check and revert back. In postman , we pass as part of header ,and other code snippets also suggested me to pass through header value. Need to check on "query" param.

Comment: Ashish , Please suggest if u have any suggestions where to add apikey